# Django query negation

Tags: django, negation

I know how to build filters and Q objects in django, but I don't know how to negate the operators that the API provides, for example for the contains operator I would like something like notcontains.

e.g.

```
q=Q(name__notcontains="SomeString")
```

This would get me all objects whose name do not contain "SomeString".

Is there some syntax that I'm missing?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You can use [`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) in place of `filter()`:

```
Entry.objects.exclude(name__contains="SomeString")
```

("give me all entries EXCEPT those with `names` containing "SomeString")

And when dealing with Q object you can use "~" symbol before Q object to represent negation. For example the following statement means "give me all Entries with `names` containing "Elephant", but NOT containing "SomeString":

```
Entry.objects.filter(Q(name__contains="Elephant") & ~Q(name__contains="SomeString"))
```

In some cases you may want to use both methods:

```
Entry.objects.exclude(Q(name__contains="Elephant") & ~Q(name__contains="SomeString"))
```

("give me all entries, EXCEPT those with `names` containing "Elephant", but NOT containing "SomeString")

Answer (score 7):

Here's the [QuerySet API reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/). [`exclude`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude-kwargs) seems to do what you want.

Comment: Great! that is exactly what I needed, although it can't be used inside a Q object, one can simply chain the filters together:
q=Q(title__contains="SomeTerm")
TheModel.objects.filter(q).exclude(title__contains="SomeTermWeDontWant")

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Either use `exclude` as Hank suggests or, for the particular `contains` case, use Q(name__regex=r'!(SomeString)') if you really really need to use the `filter`. Be warned though that `regex` is not database-agnostic, check what syntax your db supports first.